# How to connect XTONE Pro to guitar amp

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I checked some XTONE Pro interface video online, and it seems people all connect it to speaker via audio interface. There is no successful example connecting it to guitar amp.

I tried to connect its L/R output to guitar amp directly but it needs a Fender Twin Reverb max volume and guitar max volume to get it heard, totally abnormal.

Any ideas?

Comment: The impedance of the unbalanced outputs is 100 ohms and that of the balanced XLR outputs is 200 ohms. A guitar amp will expect around 100 times higher impedance.